# Generate script in SQL Server 2005 with data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2005-express

How can I generate a script in SQL Server 2005 with data in table?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the options to script data along with schema didn't seem to appear until SQL Server 2008, so I think you're stuck with third party options.

- [SSMS Tool Pack has a generate inserts option](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=8/#GIS)
- Narayana Vyas Kondreddi has an excellent [generate inserts script](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code.htm#inserts) I've been using for a few years now

Answer (score 3):

Use data publishing wizard.
step by step explanation at :
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/11/16/sql-server-2005-generate-script-with-data-from-database-database-publishing-wizard/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before, and there seems to be no direct script can be made to take all tables structures with their data.

I came around this situation by doing the following:

1. Generate a script for database architecture (RightClick on Database > Tasks > Generate Scripts > Select all tables, and script to a file)
2. Create a backup file for the database (RightClick on Database > Tasks > Backup)

Then, to take your database somewhere else:

1. Execute the database script file to create tables
2. Restore the database using [Database Name] > Restore > Database.

This worked just fine for me using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score -1):

**Update**

**The answer below is not for SQL Server 2005 as @jake mentioned. So pls ignore the answer. 
I am keeping the answer, incase someone wanted to see how to do it on other SQL Server versions**

---

Right click on the database. Then select the Tasks->Generate Scripts
[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpDEr.png)

Then, Select the table or tables which you need insert script to be generated. 
[see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhqeL.png)

Now Click next and click on Advanced and select "Types of data to script"
[see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glBqF.png)

Finally, next, next, you get all your data in insert scripts. 
Good bye excel!

Comment: Yes this is how i generated data insert scripts. Not sure why it got devoted .

Comment: The question is specifically about 2005, which doesn't seem to have this option.