# script File Creation with table data in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to simply generate the CREATE SQL script for a table and data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312576/how-to-simply-generate-the-create-sql-script-for-a-table-and-data)

I use the sql server 2005 for store the data.Now **I need to create the script File with table data**?How to do this?I try to create like,**Tasks-->generate Script**.If i use like this I get only the structure of the table not with data.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312576/how-to-simply-generate-the-create-sql-script-for-a-table-and-data

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer here:

[Generate script in SQL Server 2005 with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793414/generate-script-in-sql-server-2005-with-data)